# Sortable not working with tabs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hi I am using jQuery's sortable between multiple lists. The problem occurs when I add connect  more than one tabs list together. Desired behaviour is shown is this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vmV6F/. (simply drag a word from the one tab to the desired position in the above sentence). But as you see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prQCR/ as soon as I add the class .con to connect tabs two and three, I can no longer move any word in any of the tabs containers to either the first or second positions.

What am I doing wrong?

code below

html

```
<div id="sen" class="con">
    <p>The</p>
    <p>cat</p>
    <p>was</p>
    <p>very</p>
    <p>bad</p> 
</div>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">three</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1" class="con">
      <p>one</p>
      <p>one</p>
      <p>one</p>
      <p>one</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-2" >
     <p>two</p>
      <p>two</p>
      <p>two</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tabs-3"  >
    <p>three</p>
     <p>three</p>
     <p>three</p>
  </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("#sen, #tabs-1, #tabs-2, #tabs-3").sortable({
        connectWith: ".con"
    }).disableSelection();
 });

$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

css

```
#sen {
    width: 978px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
}

#sen p {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 50px;     
}

#tabs-1 p, #tabs-2 p, #tabs-3 p  {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px; 
}

#tabs  {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you want only to drop words from tabs to sentence you should not add class="con" to tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a jqueryui [bug](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6958), considered as notabug year ago

Seems like the reason is `display: none` on hidden tabs which confuses `sortable` plugin

The best workaround I see is to reactivate `sortable` for currently opened tab like this:

```
function activateSortable() {
    $(".con").sortable({
        connectWith: ".con"
    }).disableSelection();
};

$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event,ui){
            ui.newPanel.addClass('con')
            ui.oldPanel.removeClass('con')
            activateSortable()
        }
    });
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6GLuS/) that works like you want!

Comment: Thanks it pretty much works. I did find a slight problem thou. If you add a few words the first word of the second line is still bugged. That is, you can't place a word before it like the original problem.